# Embulk job fail using embulk-output-bigquery plugin when there's Korean in json

Tags: java, json

We use Embulk v0.8.13 plugin, embulk-input-redshift (0.7.4), plugin embulk-output-bigquery (0.4.2)

Job failed when there's Korean in JSON Error:

> org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Error) failed during waiting a Load job, get_job(vuclipdataflow-1301, embulk_load_job_bc325bd0-6b78-4ca9-954a-7915dbe4cc55), errors:[{:reason=>"invalid", :message=>"Too many errors encountered."}, {:reason=>"invalid", :location=>"/gzip/subrange/file-00000000", :message=>"CSV table references column position 20, but line starting at position:22635868 contains only 20 columns."}]
>   {"user_geo":"10","user_ccode":"ID",,"user_name":"신제군","acq_campaign":"Viu_ID_TKM"}

All this info should be in a column, but the embulk can't process the Korean correctly, the end part `acq_campaign":"Viu_ID_TKM`
will be split to a new column in the tmp csv,then cause the exception above.

How to fix it? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by adding the option, "allow_quoted_newlines".

```
# config.yml
in:
  ...
out:
  ...
  allow_quoted_newlines: true
```